# Can someone share with me an article in which the author claims that the get passive is not a passive (or at least a true passive)?

Tags: english, reference-request, passive

**Can someone share with me an article in which the author claims that the get passive is not a passive (or at least a true passive)?**
I need an article in which the author says that he or she doesn't consider the get passive to be a true passive.

Comment: What do **you** mean by "true passive"? Is it sposta be different from other passives? What kind of evidence are you looking for? How about an article that concludes that the _get_ passive is a True Passive? You just want somebody to back up your conclusion?

Comment: @jlawler: I assumed OP wants to compare the colloquial use of "get" vs the standard use of "be" in forming the passive.

Comment: Which uses of _get are "colloquial", and how does one distinguish them from the  others? Also, who's setting the "standard", and how is it distinguished from the "colloquial"?

Comment: as ya know there ain't no official standard but the de-facto standard is not to say or write anything proscribed. i think the questions getting asked by you there are the ones what should get addressed in any article i think the op is looking for cos sometimes get sounds right in passives and sometimes it doesnt and i cant put my finger on how i know but i know so maybe something could get learned from such a article if one can get found

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get+passive%22

Comment: Exactly. The 2nd result has "In spoken English, the verb get sometimes replaces the verb be in passive sentences. Use of the get-passive is considered conversational." which is weaker than "nonstandard" but could still be interpreted to be less than a "true passive". The 5th result's abstract if you click on it contains "The other does not consider the construction a type of passive, pointing out some extra semantic characteristics or pragmatic functions which are all absent in the be-passive, and instead associates the get-passive with other voice forms, such as the middle-reflexive voice."